# how to produce a single output after checking a file for a word in python

Tags: python-3.6

I am a new python user and have recently started working on a project to create a quiz in python. I want to make an account for every person who takes the quiz. I'm saving all the user names and passwords in a text file and the program will check the file for the user name and password if a user wants to log in. This is my code but when I run it it prints an output for every line on text in the file. I want just one output based on the whole file. Does somebody know how to fix this?:

```
 choice = input("are you registered user?")
    if choice == "1":
        age = input ("age? ")
        name = input ("name? ")
        yrgroup = input("yr group? ")
        username = name[:3] + age 
        print ("your username is ", username)
        password = input ("password? ")
        students = open("students.txt","a")
        students.write(password)
        students.write(" ")
        students.write(age)
        students.write(" ")
        students.write(yrgroup)
        students.write(" ")
        students.write(username)
        students.write(" ")
        students.write(name)
        students.write(" ")
        students.write("\n")
        students.close()
    elif choice == "2":
        user = input ("please enter your username: ")
        pas = input ("please enter password: ")
        with open("students.txt","r") as file:
            for line in file:
                word = line.split(" ")
                if pas in word:
                    print ("LOGGING IN")
                else:
                    print ("WRONG")
    else:
        print("invalid input")
```

It prints this when I run it:

```
 hello everyone
    are you registered user?2
    please enter your username: ale15
    please enter password: meow
    WRONG
    WRONG
    WRONG
    LOGGING IN
```

I need it to output just one line that says whether it's wrong or logging in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
user = input ("please enter your username: ")
    pas = input ("please enter password: ")
    result = False
    with open("students.txt","r") as file:
        for line in file:
            word = line.split(" ")
            if pas in word:
                result = True
    if (result):
        print('LOGGIN IN')
    else:
        print('WRONG')
```